# Can't bundle update due to multiple ruby versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to update with bundle:

```
bundle update
Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.6) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.13.7). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
Ignoring ffi-1.9.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.10
Ignoring json-1.8.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.3
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
liquid-4.0.0 requires ruby version >= 2.1.0, which is incompatible with the
current version, ruby 2.0.0p648
```

So I try

```
ruby --version
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

It seems like bundle is using a different instance of ruby?

Comment: if you using rbenv, then you can set the local folder with rbenv local x.x.x (replace x.x.x with the version that you want to use, then rbenv rehash, gem install bundler  and finally bundle install / update

Comment: Are you using some ruby virtual env like rbenv or RVM ?

Comment: how can I check that??

Comment: Add the output of `gem env` to the question

Comment: Your `bundler` might be linked to a different version of Ruby. `which bundler` can help find out which one you're actually running.

Answer (score 1):

What version is used when you run `bundle env`?

You could try reinstalling bundler with: `gem install bundler`

But first you can read a little more about it [here](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4260)